# how to parametrize a single query

Tags: jpa, prepared-statement

i would like to have a query that contains  all the category selected
something like :
in ProductDao

```
enter public List<Product> listselected(List <Product> selectedCategories) { 
     TypedQuery<Product> findQuery = em
            .createQuery(
                    "SELECT DISTINCT p FROM Product p WHERE p.idcategory='1' AND p.idcategory='2' etc ORDER BY p.idproduct",
                    Product.class);
    return findQuery.getResultList();} here
```

but parametrized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this syntax:

```
em.createQuery("SELECT DISTINCT p FROM Product p WHERE p.idcategory IN (:categories) ORDER BY p.idproduct", Product.class)
         .setParameter("categories", selectedCategories)
         .getResultList();
```

Now, I don't know how you mapped a `Category`, but if it's an entity and `Product` has a field `category`, you can rewrite the query with:

```
List<Category> selectedCategories =...;
em.createQuery("SELECT DISTINCT p FROM Product p WHERE p.category IN (:categories) ORDER BY p.idproduct", Product.class)
         .setParameter("categories", selectedCategories)
         .getResultList();
```

I don't know if this is standard JPA, but it should work with Hibernate ORM.

Answer (score 0):

Given I understand what you're trying to do, you could try using the `IN` operator in your query:

```
TypedQuery<Product> findQuery = em
            .createQuery(
                    String.format("SELECT DISTINCT p FROM Product p WHERE p.idcategory IN (%s) ORDER BY p.idproduct", selectedCategories),
                    Product.class);
```

edit: See Davides answer for a safer way of setting the parameter